# how to break two string in viewbags in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 public ActionResult AgentHome()
    {
        ViewBag.IsfromHome = true;
        ViewBag.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
        var username=GeneralLogic.GetUserName();
        var imdcode = Entities.tblUserDetails.Where(a => a.userlevel == "L0" && a.UserAccountID == Entities.tblUserDetails.Where(s => s.LoginID == username).Select(s => s.UserAccountID).FirstOrDefault()).Select(a=>a.IMDCode).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.imdcode = imdcode;

        return View(ViewBag);
    }
```

This is my view.
in that how to break the two string

please any one can help how to break a string

```
  if (ViewBag.IsfromHome != null)
    {
        if (ViewBag.IsfromHome == true)
        {
            //  url += "Thanks and Regards"
            url += "USERNAME :";
            url = url + ViewBag.Username + "  " + " ";
            url += "IMDCODE :";
            url = url + ViewBag.imdcode;

        }
    }
```

Comment: what does "break the two string in viewbag" mean for you can you explain

Comment: after execute that show in only one line of both statement like

Comment: UserName:abc  IMDCODE: 1234 but i want next line

Comment: but i want next line? means

show the exact result you expect .

Comment: username after that next line that IMDcode should be display

Comment: meances in next line that IMDCODE should be display not in one line

Comment: USERNAME :superadmin   IMDCODE :IMD00486  in this i want that IMDCODE should be display below of USERNAME

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
        url += "USERNAME :";
        url = url + ViewBag.Username + "  " + "<br />";
        url += "IMDCODE :";
        url = url + ViewBag.imdcode;'
```

Hope it should work.

Or you can use

```
     url += "USERNAME :"+ViewBag.Username + "  " + "<br />"+"IMDCODE :"+ViewBag.imdcode
```